# JS regex exec the inner string between delimiters and check for broken delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field in a form that I have to check for certain markup that we have setup.

The delimiter is `{!`, `}`.

I would like to match everything that's inside the delimiters.

```
content = /regex/g.exec('{!content}')
```

futher more the input string can have more than one markup in it.

```
input = '{!content} {!other}';
['content','other'] = /regex/g.exec('{!content} {!other}')
```

This is the first part of the problem, now it gets to the fun part.

I also have where certain markup delimiters are not ended correctly and I have to check for those also.

In this case I would like to get:

```
input = '{!content {!other} {!broken';
['{!content', 'other', '{!broken'] = /regex/g.exec(input);
```

Update *** found a case where the orginal solution from @MikeM is not capturing something that I would like. If the starting delimiter is by itself, I need those to show up in the results array. If the starting delimiter is at the end of the string then it wont capture.

```
input = '{!content {!other} {!';
['{!content', 'other', '{!'] = /regex/g.exec(input);
```

Comment: Please read the faq on how to format your questions properly with markdown.

Comment: Regarding your edit: just change the last `+` to `*`, i.e _one or more_ to _zero or more_, so the regex becomes `/\{!([^{}]+)\}|(\{![^{}]*)/g`.

Comment: you know I tried that before my update and it didnt work, possibly cache didn't clear when I refreshed my browser :( ... Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following if `{` and `}` are not allowed in the content

```
var m,    
    result = [],
    str = '{!content {!other} {!broken',
    reg = /\{!([^{}]+)\}|(\{![^{}]+)/g;

while ( m = reg.exec( str ) ) {
    result.push( m[1] || m[2] );
}

console.log( result );   // [ "{!content ", "other", "{!broken" ]
```

It would though, grab the spaces following unclosed content.

Update:

To capture content without including any leading or trailing whitespace you could use the following - written in longer form for clarity.

```
var m,    
    result = [],
    str = '{!content {!other} {!broken  {!    broken {! content }',
    reg = /\{!\s*([^{}]+?)\s*\}|\{!\s*([^{}]+?)\s*(?=\{|$)/g;

m = reg.exec( str );

while ( m != null ) {   

    if ( m[1] != null ) {
        result.push( m[1] );
    } else {  // m[2] cannot be null
        result.push( '{!' + m[2] );
    }
    m = reg.exec( str );
}

console.log( result );   
// [ "{!content", "other", "{!broken", "content", "{!broken", "content" ]
```

For more on `exec`, see [MDN exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Comment: I really need to learn more of how to use this site correctly so that it eases the pain for people who are trying.  
  
Thank you all.  

Damn ending line double space line breaks!!!!

Comment: Even '{!content {!other} {!broken this will be part of broken {!good} missingleft}' works

Comment: That's a good approach, not allowing braces in the content (`[^{}]`) makes it a *lot* easier. Good thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Returns an array of matches:

```
(str.match(/\{\!.*?.(?=[\{\}])|\{\!.+?$/g)||[]).map(function(m){return m.substring(2);});
```

- `(_.match(...)||[])` is an idiom. Match returns `null` if there is no match found, but it's usually more convenient to get an empty array instead. `||[]` fixes that.
- The regular expression finds matches between `{!` and terminators in an non-greedy way. That is, it's looking for the first `}` it can find after the `{!`. We also have to be tolerant of running into a mismatching open brace `{` and the end of the line and pass these through as possible matches.

  [image]
- Matches from the above always start with `{!` but have no terminating delimiter. The only thing left to do is to peel it off, so we can `map` the array to `substring(2)`. If you want to get rid of whitespaces before and after, you could make this `substring(2).trim()`.

Comment: `match` doesn't capture groups AFAIK so the result will have the delimiters included.

Comment: sorry I added more to the question.

Comment: @elcanrs That depends on if the regex is `g`

Comment: sorry I edited the question as quickly as I could but @elcanrs was too fast :)

Comment: @BruceLim Are you showing that your delimiters can be nested? Or is an instance of `{!foo {! bar}` considered (a) invalid or (b) to have the contents `foo {! bar` or (c) an incomplete version of `{!foo {! bar}}` with matches `foo {! bar}` and `bar`?

Comment: There are nested delimiters but the real problem I'm trying to solve is the broken delimiters. like '{!broken {!good}';

Comment: @BruceLim If they can be nested we need to write a parser, if not we can use negative lookahead

Comment: No nesting, just multiple ones in the string. Had to make sure before I answered this one :)

Comment: @BruceLim What do you want to do when you encounter `{! foo {! bar`? Interpret as `{! foo }{! bar}`? (Auto-closing), throw an error, or interpret as `{! foo \{\! bar}`?

Comment: @Plynx    
I would like the both results to be captured with the delimiters if that's possible.  
So correctly closed markups will be captured without the delimiters but an incorrectly finished one's will be captured with the left delimiter.  
In your case above ['{!foo', '{!bar'] is the result I would like to get.  

btw, linebreak spaces are not working for me.

Comment: '{!bad {!other} {!broke' returned ["bad {!other"]  

This is opposite behavior and it didn't grab the 3rd one.

@Plynx I appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Where are you getting those graphics from? Pretty cool. Thanks @Plynx for all the help.

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/ Great tool. As printed, and especially with escape character, regular expressions aren't friendly for visual parsing, no?

Comment: Especially the long one's that reach all the way to China!! I hope no one thinks I'm racist over that comment :p (I'm asian btw)